# Deleting text between two strings and quote in php using preg_replace

Tags: php

I have this string:

```
AND wp_posts.post_location = 'location1' AND wp_posts.post_title = 'RANDOMQUERY' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'custom' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
```

I want to remove this part which consist random string:

```
 AND wp_posts.post_title = 'RANDOMQUERY'
```

Become like this:

```
AND wp_posts.post_location = 'location1' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'custom' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
```

How to do it in php?

Comment: why not `str_replace`? And where is your code in which you are facing an issue?

Comment: I suggest this looks like Wordpress, which means there's probably a better hook to use to change the behavior of Queries, eg `pre_get_posts` etc https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference

Comment: @M.Hemant str_replace as far as i know only for static string. It can't  replace for dynamic string inside the quote

Comment: @Scuzzy wordpress doesnt have built in to search title using 'LIKE'. They can only search title using '='. I want to remove this original title query and add my own query to achive this goal.

Comment: Implementation of dupe advice: https://3v4l.org/5rnoP

Comment: This looks like an interesting possibility https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/wp-query-with-post-title-like-something

Comment: You must use regex: preg_replace("/AND wp_posts.post_title = '.*?'/", '', $string);

Answer (score -1):

Better use **mysqli_real_escape_string**
with out changing the text.

For more details https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Hi, how mysqli_real_escape_string can replace/remove part of dynamic string?